# Export everything into swf?

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript, export, embed

I have linked music into my .fla with this actionscript:

```
public var chpt1Theme:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest('Interlude1.mp3'));

public var chpt1ThemeSC:SoundChannel;
```

How do I package the music into the swf so the swf is completely independent? When I export -> movie, the sound is not included?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the sound file included within the SWF file you will need to import/embed it into your FLA's library and reference the class name for that sound. The following example is taken from the first resource I posted below:

```
var drum:DrumSound = new DrumSound(); 
var channel:SoundChannel = drum.play();
```

Here are some further resources:

[Working with embedded sounds](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d24.html)

[Using Flash Professional - Sound](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7ce9a.html)